# Query against an Oracle database using sqlplus returns a column that is an empty single character wide column

Tags: linux, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

In an Oracle 11_2 database, I am attempting to run a query on a table, client_info. In SQL Developer I see the full column with the first 10 client names. When I try to run the same query in sqlplus on my local machine inside WSL, or a remote linux server, the results come back as a single character wide column with nothing in the rows but empty space.

I've tried with Oracle sqlplus versions 11_2, 12_2, and 21_10.

I also tried the same query on sqlplus that exists on a citrix instance, using 11_2, that DOES show the results.

I checked the NLS_CHARACTERSET as US7ASCII.

I am guessing it's something to do with the encoding and my terminal settings are some how at fault, but I'm honestly not finding what. I've tried the same query in a python and perl script as well but no results return either.

Table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE client_info (
    client_id    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    client_name  VARCHAR2(35 BYTE),
    account_type VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)
```

Failed Query:

```
SELECT client_name FROM client_info WHERE account_type = 'IMPORTANT' AND rownum <= 10 ORDER BY client_name;
```

Output:

```
C
-











10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Working output:

```
CLIENT_NAME
-----------------------------------
CL0038
CL0105
CL0105
CL0116
CL0123
CL0128
CL0128
CL0276
CL0318
CL0318

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

(edit: adding the output of dump as requested)

From sqlplus:

```
SQL> SELECT dump(client_name) FROM client_info WHERE account_type = 'IMPORTANT' AND ROWNUM <= 10 ORDER BY client_name;

DUMP(client_name)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

From SQL Developer:

```
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,48,51,56
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,48,53
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,48,53
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,49,54
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,50,51
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,50,56
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,49,50,56
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,50,55,54
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,51,49,56
Typ=1 Len=6: 67,76,48,51,49,56
```

My wsl instance and linux systems show the following locale settings:

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any suggestions on what to check next would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be hitting a different database or schema, with a different table definition (and data). What do you see if you `desc` the table in each session? You can also `dump()` the values to see what they really contain. Also your query doesn't have an order by so which 10 rows you're getting is indeterminate; and your 'working' output has a different column name. It does look like you're just connecting to different things.

Comment: I'll try the desc/dump out. As for the different databases I don't /believe/ so, and even if so I have tried reconnecting many times from different systems and failed to get the output. Whereas I can consistently get output from sql developer.
As for the table name in the output, that was my fault, I was changing names to protect the innocent and missed that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally heard back from our DBA. I'm told that this data is in a VPD (Virtual Private Database) and has certain safeguards in place to prevent the data from displaying. In this case it is based on the combination of the database login and the username of the system (ie the linux username). If those two names aren't in the database as having permission to view that table/column/whatever it won't show up.

Hope this helps someone else out down the road.